# Microsoft Azure é recomendado para hospedar site de jogos?

Tags: php, windows, microsoft-azure

Eu quero adquirir um plano da Microsoft Azure mas tenho dúvidas.

Eu sou desenvolvedor de jogos então queria saber se é recomendado hospedar o site e hospedar os arquivos do servidor em uma máquina Windows.

Se for queria saber se a hospedagem de site deles suporta PHP?

Comment: Com certeza!Como exemplo podemos citar o jogo Titan Fall que foi todo hospedado no Azure. Acho que é um bom exemplo. Quanto a suportar PHP, suporta de boa. Tem um DevCenter -> http://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/develop/php/

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 7):

Sim, suporta PHP conforme uma [central para desenvolvedores PHP](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/develop/php/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) da plataforma. Então pode fazer seu *site* sem medo. Se é recomendado ou não, só você pode dizer. Minha opinião não ajudaria nada, mas o que pode ser respondido objetivamente, está aí.

A plataforma admite essencialmente tudo o que qualquer *site* precisa, dificilmente você irá sentir falta de algum recurso, mas se tem alguma preocupação muito específica, terá que analisar ponto por ponto do que eles colocam na documentação. O básico certamente está tudo lá, incluindo domínios próprios. O "painel" deles é bem diferente do CPanel mas existe uma maneira semelhante e bem completa.

Ao contrário do que algumas pessoas acham, o Azure suporta Linux também.

Answer (score 3):

Gustavo,

Tenha em mente que a plataforma Microsoft Azure é muito mais que apenas um local para hospedar websites ou arquivos.

Vou imaginar que vc precisa hospedar uma plataforma para suportar um game que você criou. Com Microsoft Azure você poderá:

- Hospedar o hotsite do seu game com Azure Web App. Podendo escalar (aumentar poder de entrega - banda -  do site ou aumentar seu processamento em segundos. Ou mesmo diminuir o consumo de recursos e economizar muita grana)
- Hospedar Backend do seu game com Azure API App. Escalando de forma independente do site e realocando geograficamente onde vc tem mais gamers.
- Extender seu game à outros recursos sem usar código fonte com Azure Logic App. Você pode fazer twitties se o jogador bater um record, ou mesmo enviar um SMS para confirmar autenticação. Enfim, você pode comunicar seu jogo com outros sistemas, sem se preocupar em conhecer a fundo esses outros sistemas. E sem mexer no código fonte do seu game.
- Criar banck-end de aplicativos mobile do seu jogo, independe de plataforma - android, ios, Windows - afim de disparar notificações nos celulares e tablets de quem tiver o app do seu game e um NomeDeJogador (gamertag) .
- Fazer backup de todos os dados da sua plataforma do game de forma rápida, tudo em nuvem, com toda segurança possível. Pode testar a recuperação do backup em minutos.
- Pode criar meios de outros desenvolvedores criarem side-games ou outros aplicativos que conversem seu com seu game usando Azure API Management. E criar planos de pagamentos e monetizar tudo isso.
- Pode criar propagandas em vídeo - igual que o YouTube faz - e transmitir entre uma fase e outra do seu game com Azure Media Service. Outra forma de monetização.

Enfim, existe um mundo de possibilidades que você pode alcançar usando Azure. Hospedar o hotsite do seu game, não será nenhuma preocupação se usar Azure.